# Why is the image of the upper half-plane under a mapping of the form $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ the lower half-plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, functions

My textbook says that the image of the upper half-plane under a mapping of the form $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ with $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}, \: ad-bc<0$ is the lower half-plane without offering explanation. Why is this obviously the case?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Multiply numerator and denominator by $c\overline {z} +d$ and write down the imaginary part of the numerator. You would get $(ad-bc) $ times the imaginary part of $z$ so this is negative when the imaginary part of $z$  is positive.

Comment: Note also that $f$ maps the reals into the reals, so (given that the mapping is one-to-one from the Riemann sphere onto itself) it should be one half-plane or the other.

Answer (score 1):

Since all four coefficients are real, the mapping needs to map the real line to itself. So the image of the upper half-plane has the same boundary that the upper half-plane has. That narrows the list of possible things that it could be.

Comment: Note, however, that if we do not include $\infty$ the mapping may not be defined on a point of the real line, namely $-\frac dc$

Comment: @Caffeine : But the image of the open upper half-plane would still be the open lower half-plane.

Comment: Yes. The only "problem" is that for your claim to be correct one needs to use the riemann sphere, instead of $\mathbb{C}$, i.e. to use the extended real line. Otherwise your claim "the mapping needs to map the real line to itself" is false, since $\infty \notin \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Caffeine : I see. Alright, it needs to map $\mathbb R\cup\{\infty\}$ to itself.